# Quick Sort implementation in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, sorting, quick-sort

Implemented the quick sort algorithm in python, It was just for learning it, now I want to port it to C.

Thoughts on the quality of my python implementation?

```py
from random import randint, shuffle

def swap(array, a, b):
    array[a], array[b] = array[b], array[a]


def quick_sort(array, start=0, end=None):
    if end is None:
        end = len(array) - 1

    if end - start >= 1:
        pivot = array[end]
        a = start
        b = end - 1
        while not a > b:
            if not array[a] > pivot:
                a += 1
                continue
            else:
                if array[b] < pivot:
                    swap(array, a, b)
                    a += 1
                b -= 1
        swap(array, a, end)
        quick_sort(array, start, a - 1)
        quick_sort(array, a + 1, end)


arr = [randint(0, 30) for _ in range(20)]
print(arr)
quick_sort(arr)
print(arr)
```

Comment: It works, so far, I didn't found any error.

Comment: OK, just checking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Magic Numbers

```
arr = [randint(0, 30) for _ in range(20)]
```

What are `0`, `30`, and `20` supposed to represent? I would assign these to variables to make it more clear

## Type Hints

This

```
def swap(array, a, b):
```

can be this

```
def swap(array: list, a: int, b: int) -> None:
```

These allow you to show what types of parameters are accepted, and what types are returned from the functions.

## Main Guard

This

```
arr = [randint(0, 30) for _ in range(20)]
print(arr)
quick_sort(arr)
print(arr)
```

should be put in a main guard, like so

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    arr = [randint(0, 30) for _ in range(20)]
    print(arr)
    quick_sort(arr)
    print(arr)
```

This prevents this code from running if you decide to import this module from another module/program.